# Python '//' integer division method in classes

Tags: python-3.x, integer-division

How can I add an integer division `//` method to a class?

I can add a subtraction method like `def __sub__(self, other):`, so how can I do it with `//`?

I looked for this online, and couldn't find anything.

Using Python 3.

Comment: `__floordiv__`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks. Submit an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`__floordiv__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv).